# PendingResult.setResultCallback() always returns the statusCode success

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client

if i connect my google watch with a mobile device successfully, and then disable the bluetooth connection (for test reasons) and make a google api client call to my mobile device, the pending result always returns the status code success, even if its not successfull because there is no more connection

**async task for the request**

```
class DataTask  extends AsyncTask<Node, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Node... nodes) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Request requestObject = new Request();
        requestObject.setType(Constants.REQUEST_TYPE);
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(requestObject);

        PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create(Constants.PATH_REQUEST);
        dataMap.setUrgent();
        dataMap.getDataMap().putString(Constants.KEY_REQUEST, jsonString);
        PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
        DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult = Wearable.DataApi
                .putDataItem(googleApiClient, request).await();

        boolean connected = googleApiClient.isConnected();
        PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, request);
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status = dataItemResult.getStatus();

                DataItem dataItem = dataItemResult.getDataItem();
                boolean dataValid = dataItemResult.getDataItem().isDataValid();
                boolean canceled = status.isCanceled();
                boolean interrupted = status.isInterrupted();
                float statusCode = status.getStatusCode();


                if(status.isSuccess()){ // expected to be false because there is no bluetooth connection anymore
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success");
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failure");
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

why do i not get a false for status.isSuccess?

the only solution i found is to write following code inside the AsyncTask:

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient).await().getNodes();
if(connectedNodes.size() == 0){
    // no connection
}
```

is it not possible to check if the request was successfully inside the ResultCallback?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `getStatus()` call for `DataItemResult` is only indicating whether the call was successfully passed off to the Data API, **not** whether it was successfully relayed to another node. The Data API is asynchronous - it's a "store and forward" architecture - so it's not reasonable to expect it to notify you immediately of successful delivery.

In fact, I don't think that there is a way to determine from the Data API when your `DataItem` has been delivered **at all**. Your `getConnectedNodes` technique is only telling you that the watch is connected, not that the data has been delivered. If you need proof of delivery, you'll probably have to implement that yourself, perhaps using the Message API.

One other note: given you've wrapped your code in an `AsyncTask`, there's no need to use `PendingResult.setResultCallback`. You can simply `await` the result inline: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#sync-waiting